# Cannot enable shopt extglob from bash command string argument? (temporarily set shopt extglob)

Tags: bash, shopt

I'm using `bash` version:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
```

So, say I have these files:

```
$ ls
a.txt  aa  b.txt  bb  README
```

Say, I want to list anything but `aa`; (EDIT: but I do not want to enable extglob permanently - just want to enable it for a single command run!) if I do this:

```
$ bash

$ shopt -s extglob

$ ls -x ./!(aa)
./a.txt  ./b.txt  ./README

./bb:
bb.txt

$ exit
```

... then it seems `shopt` works fine; but if I try it as a one-liner, inside a command string:

```
$ bash -c 'shopt -s extglob ; ls -x ./!(aa)'
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `shopt -s extglob ; ls -x ./!(aa)'
```

... although, this (running in subshell with parentheses) works (although, it seems it changes the `shopt` also for the parent shell? and actually, for all open shells under MSYS2 ?!??):

```
$ echo $(shopt -s extglob; ls -x ./!(aa))
./a.txt ./b.txt ./README ./bb: bb.txt
```

Why does this happen - why can't the `shopt -s extglob` be enabled/executed when running as part of a bash command that is specified from the command line (via the command line argument `-c`)?

Comment: Does `bash -O extglob -c 'ls -x ./!(aa)'` work? (yes it does)

Comment: The _question_ in the dupe is slightly different, but the _answer_ would be identical.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda - that seems to work, but I cannot tell now if it is because your command set extglob, or because the `$(shopt -s extglob)` subshell command enabled extglob (in what it seems to be ALL of my MSYS2 `bash` instances!?) I just wanted this option enabled temporarily, for one run of a command (edited my post to clarify) ...  Also thanks - the dupe explains why I'm seeing what I'm seeing, so it is an answer to this Q as well. Thanks again!

Comment: To enable `extglob` for a single command, use `bash -O extglob -c 'somecommand'`, or `shopt -s extglob` on its own line before the command, and then `shopt -u extglob`. Running `shopt` in a subshell (e.g. a command substitution) will not change it in the parent shell. I guess you must have enabled the option in the parent shell already by mistake.